# Given a probability generating function what is the $r$th term

Tags: probability, generating-functions

Given that pgf is $G(H(\xi))=\frac{1+\xi}{3-\xi}$. Where $H(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\xi)$ and $G(\xi) = \frac{\xi}{2-\xi}$. And that $G(H(\xi))$ is the pgf of some random variable $Y$. How does one get the value of $P(Y=r)$, I realize that I have to differentiate $r$ times and then set $\xi$ to $0$. But in practice..

$$\frac{d^r}{d\xi^r} G(H(\xi)) \Bigr|_{\substack{\xi=0}}$$

I was thinking of making a substitution $H(\xi)=u$, but $\frac{d^r}{d\xi^r} \neq \frac{d^r}{du^r} \frac{d^r u}{d\xi^r} $

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac{1+\xi}{3-\xi}=\frac13\frac{1+\xi}{1-\frac\xi3}=\frac13(1+\xi)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac\xi3\right)^k\;.
$$

Comment: this is the $P(Y=r)$?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: No, this is a rewriting of the function that makes it more obvious how to obtain $P(Y=r)$, the coefficient of $\xi^r$. (It clearly can't be $P(Y=r)$, since it doesn't contain $r$.)

Comment: I actually just divided the numerator by denominator to obtain: $-1+\frac{4}{3-\xi}$. And then it is also easier to see what the $r$th derivative is. I am still obtaining an incorrect result... I obtain: $P(Y=r) = \frac{4 r!}{3^{r+1}}$, where in fact, there should be no $r!$ in the numerator.